# Which is correct {What does make/What makes} the water rise at night?

Tags: word-choice, wh-questions

I'm still confused on how can I use "do/does/did" in wh question.

Which one is correct?

> What **does make** the water rise at night?
> What **makes** the water rise at night?"

Comment: Where/when does water rise at night? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can both be correct depending on the context.

"What does make the water rise at night?" implies there has been a previous statement from another person of what does *not* make the water rise at night (which is being responded to). For example:

Person 1: "The tides don't make the water rise at night."

Person 2: "What *does* make the water rise at night?"

"What makes the water rise at night?" is a neutral question which makes sense to me.

Most often, "what makes the water rise at night?" would be accurate and common usage.

Comment: Also, the previous statement could be something like 'I found out what makes the water rise at night', with no immediate follow-up.